# Discrete/continous mixed Plot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot two functions in ONE plot, one given as an analytic expression, the other one is numeric.

How can I plot the analytic function continously and discrete points for the numeric function in the SAME plot?

Comment: Please post your data and function. Maybe by use `Show`

Comment: If you want to plot the analytic function and add discrete points for the numeric function, you may do this using the option `Epilog`of `Plot`. If you want to plot both functions together, you may plot them separately (without displaying them) and then combine them using `Show`.

Comment: `Show[Plot[f, {x, 0, 3}], ListPlot[data], PlotRange -> All]`. If your numeric function is an interpolating function `g` over an interval, say `{0, 3}`, then `Plot[{f, g[x]}, {x, 0, 3}]` will do it, but it connect the interpolation data with a smooth interpolating curve; alternatively, using `ListPlot[g]` in the first code will plot the interpolation points without connecting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) and [`DiscretePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html)

```
Show[
 Plot[Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, 10}],
 DiscretePlot[
  Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

`Plot` and [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
Show[
 Plot[Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, 10}],
 ListPlot[
  {#, Fibonacci[#]} & /@ Range[0, 10],
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Filling -> Axis]]
```

`Plot` with [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
Plot[Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, 10},
 Epilog -> {LightRed,
   Line[{{#, 0}, {#, Fibonacci[#]}}] & /@ Range[0, 10],
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{#, Fibonacci[#]} & /@ Range[0, 10]]}]
```

`Plot` and [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)

```
Show[
 Plot[Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, 10}],
 Graphics[{LightRed,
   Line[{{#, 0}, {#, Fibonacci[#]}}] & /@ Range[0, 10],
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{#, Fibonacci[#]} & /@ Range[0, 10]]}]]
```